# How to calculate Inverse variance weight of several pearsons r correlations

Tags: meta-analysis, pearson-r

I have a set of pearsons r effect sizes , converted to fishers z scores for meta analysis. I am wondering what data I need to calculate an inverse variance weight for each effect size and how I calculate these please? Also , is there an easy online calculator or spss method for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I you have the sample sizes, which I assume you do then the standard error is

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt(N-3)}
$$

So to get the sampling variance you just square that.

$$
\frac{1}{(N-3)}
$$

Comment: Thanks mdewey. Am I correct in thinking that I need to use the above formulas for each individual effect size (not a total or average of all) while in the form of a fishers z score please?

Comment: Yes, for each one.

Comment: Also , I have two different sample sizes related to two correlations ( both averaged in fishers z) in one article as it uses two studies within it. Is it acceptable to calculate an average of the two sample sizes for the standard error and inverse variance calculation please?

Comment: Hi mdewey - when you say "So to get the sampling variance you just square that" - do you mean N as in sample size or the calculated standard error please?

Comment: Yes, it is the sample size.

Comment: Thanks mdewey but , pardon my lack of understanding , should I not be using the calculated standard error to calculate the variance? I am confused as the formula presented in Lipsey and Wilson instructs me to use the following formula = 1 / standard error squared

Comment: Ok I now understand this. Thanks for your help. I have the sample sizes but for some correlations there are two or more sample sizes. How do I create an average of these please?

Comment: Or is it the case that N is the two sample sizes combined to be applied in the above formula?