# Calculating variance from standard error of pearsons r correlations z scores

Tags: variance, meta-analysis, pearson-r

I understand that to calculate the standard error of a pearsons r correlation converted to a z score you follow - 
1 / (√N−3)

But how do you calculate the variance from the standard error please? I have instructions to follow -

1 / standard error squared. Is this correct please?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of minor variations of the same issue: 1. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360718/how-to-calculate-inverse-variance-weight-of-several-pearsons-r-correlations

2. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360732/independent-non-independent-effect-sizes-correlations-for-meta-analysis


3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360736/calculating-corrected-mean-population-level-estimates-of-criterion-related-valid

... ctd

Comment: ctd... Please consider carefully whether perhaps some of these questions are similar enough that they can be combined. At the very least you should point to the earlier questions for context (and so people can see that they're not providing answers you already have)

Comment: @mdewey. Right. Sorry. Deleted.